# Can't display javascript object properties in mandrill template using handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, handlebars.js, mandrill

I am trying to display dynamic content by using the mandrill template api in a node project.

I have followed the docs and looked at plenty of examples, and for the most part can get things working.

However, when I try to access properties of an object that I pass through the api in the mandrill template, it does not display anything.

Here is my mandrill template (using handlebars):

```
<p>{{greeting}} {{person.firstName}},</p>
<p>{{greeting}} {{person.0.firstName}},</p>
<p>Your location is {{person.location}}.</p>
```

Now, the greeting does display the value passed in the global_merge_vars part. But the properties for the person object do not get displayed, as if they are undefined.

Here is part of the json being sent:

```
var greeting = "Hello ";
var person = {firstName:"testfname",location:"testlocation"};

var globalMergeVars = [
    {"name": "greeting","content":greeting},
    {"name": "person","content": person},
];
```

Am I not passing the object correctly or naming the 'name' property correctly in the api call? I have tried a bunch of different things. I know that I could create multiple vars inside the globalMergeVars object instead of passing the entire person object, however I have a lot more properties attached to the person object.

I have also successfully used an each loop for an array of items and that all gets displayed correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @mrpetem? I've asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071092/sending-object-as-a-variable-to-mandrill-via-rails before coming across yours...

Comment: If it's useful for you, or anyone else visiting here, I've found the solution through my own question when using Rails, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071092/sending-object-as-a-variable-to-mandrill-via-rails.

Comment: having same issue. Except, I can access some properties at the same llevel, but not others. looks like the ones failing to show up are the ones in camel case