# Sending object as a variable to Mandrill via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, handlebars.js, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm converting an email template from Rails to Mandrill, the content for which requires a fair amount of data, some of which is nested through several associations.

Therefore, I'd like to pass objects via Mandrill's global_merge_vars, such as the (simplified) following:

```
[{ 'name'=>'order', 'content'=> @order.to_json(include:
                                                { user: { only: :first_name } },
                                                  methods: [:method1,
                                                            :method2,
                                                            :method3,
                                                            :method4])
}]
```

Which passes through to the mandrill template under the `order` variable similar to the following:

```
{"id":11,"number":"xxxx","item_total":"112.0"...
 "user":{"first_name":"Steve"},"method1":"£0.00","method2":"£112.00",
 "method3":"£112.00","method4":"£0.00"}
```

The problem is, I can't access anything within `order` (using Handlebars), i.e. `{{order.id}}`, `{{order['id']}}` etc. wont work.

It's not an option to break out data into a large number of variables, as some elements are collections and their associations.

I believe the problem occurs as everything is stringified when the variables are compiled for Mandrill -- therefore breaking the JSON object -- with the following a snippet of what is sent across:

```
"global_merge_vars"=>[{"name"=>"order", "content"=>"{\"id\":11,
\"number\":\"xxxx\",\"item_total\":\"112.0\"...
```

I can't seem to find any documentation / suggestions for dealing with this, so am wondering whether this it's possible to pass data of this nature, and, if so, how to correctly pass it to be able to access the objects in the Mandrill template. Any advice greatly appreciated!

Steve.

Comment: you can access it like `|* variable*|`

Comment: Thanks @pitabasprathal, I'm using the Handlebar syntax instead - would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[{ 'name'=>'order', 'content'=> JSON.parse(@order.to_json(include:
                                            { user: { only: :first_name } },
                                              methods: [:method1,
                                                        :method2,
                                                        :method3,
                                                        :method4]))
}]
```

Comment: That's done it, thanks for the help! Strangely, I had tried this, although I had my Handlebars syntax wrong at the time: I was searching `order['id']` which doesn't work, with the correct implementation `order.id`. Combining the two has got me where I need to be. Much appreciated.